# Jquery getting only one dynamic input value instead of multiple ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input that dynamically generated values:

```
<input type="hidden" class="ser_id"  name="ser_id_name" value="{{ ser_id }}">
```

I also have a button that is generated dynamically with:

```
 <button name="get_id_name"  class="get_id_class" id="get_id" >Get it</button>
```

The input implicitly generates the following ids as separate elements:

```
125-BDA-9WG
POL-548-3S6
8d4-35S-WE6
```

An HTML layout of the elements would be as follows:

[image]

Upon checking the source code, the inputs are dynamically generated as bellow:

```
<div class="ser_ids">
      <div class="ser_input">
          <input type="text" class="ser_id"  name="ser_id_name" value="125-BDA-9WG">
          <button name="get_id_name"  class="get_id_class" id="get_id" >get ID</button>
        </div>

      <div class="ser_input">
          <input type="text" class="ser_id"  name="ser_id_name" value="POL-548-3S6">
          <button name="get_id_name"  class="get_id_class" id="get_id" >get ID</button>
        </div>

        <div class="ser_input">
          <input type="text" class="ser_id"  name="ser_id_name" value="8d4-35S-WE6">
          <button name="get_id_name"  class="get_id_class" id="get_id" >get ID</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

I get the input value in a function as follows:

```
  var ser_id = $('.ser_id').val();
  console.log('Ser Id : ' + ser_id);  //when I click on any of the 3 buttons, I get only the first ID logged - no matter what.
```

And then I use this id to concatenate a URL within an ajax call as follows:

```
  $('.get_id_class').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
               dataType: 'json', 
               url: 'API URL' + ser_id,
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (res) {
                 alert('JSON RESPONSE' + res.serStatus);

                 if(res.serStatus.orderId == "OK"){
                   alert('STATUS IS: is OK');
                 } else{
                   alert('STATUS IS NOT OK ');
                 }
               }
    }); 
});
```

I have the above ajax request being called on a button event click that is automatically generated for each ID. In other words, I have 3 buttons automatically generated for the automatically generated IDs. The issue is whenever I click on any of these buttons I only get a response with the first ID. The concatenation is always linked to this ID `125-BDA-9WG` even if I click on the other 2 buttons.

Comment: How is it supposed to know which one you want? You need to select a specific input, not all the inputs in the class. How are the inputs and buttons related? Show your HTML.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited my post to show the related button with its onClick event. Hopefully that helps pointing out where the issue is.

Comment: How are the buttons and inputs related to each other? Are they both in the same DIV?

Comment: Yes I do have both of them in a single DIV element.

Comment: Can you show how they're all laid out? Show an example with two inputs and two buttons.

Comment: I have attached an image of the input and buttons layout. Upon checking the source code, I have 3 dives - respectively.

Comment: I don't need an image, I need to see the HTML. I need to know how deeply nested they are in the common DIV, if the DIV has a class that can be used, etc.

Comment: Basically, you need to use `$(this).closest("some common ancestor").find(".ser_id").val()`

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.siblings()` to get the input in the same DIV as the button.

```
$('.get_id_class').click(function() {
  let ser_id = $(this).siblings(".ser_id").val();
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'API URL' + ser_id,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(res) {
      alert('JSON RESPONSE' + res.serStatus);

      if (res.serStatus.orderId == "OK") {
        alert('STATUS IS: is OK');
      } else {
        alert('STATUS IS NOT OK ');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

You could also use `$(this).prev().val()` or `$(this).closest(".ser_input").find(".ser_id").val()`.

BTW, IDs should be unique, you shouldn't repeat `id="get_id"` on every button.

Comment: I've answered questions like this dozens of times. You can use `siblings()`, `prev()`, `closest(...).find()`. At least one of these methods should be obvious if you understand the basic principles.